# Robot Framework before and after all tests

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to call a Suite Init and Suite Teardown before all tests and after all tests in robot framework.

I have dir structure like

```
XYZ
     - X1
     - X2
```

I tried writing a `__init__.robot` in XYZ dir but that didn't help.

Comment: The normal way is to put `__init__.robot` in XYZ; if it didn't help, can you describe what "didn't help" means, and also show the command line you used to run the tests?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to create a file named `__init__.robot` in the parent folder. In that file you can put a suite setup or teardown (using normal robot syntax in the settings table) that will get run at the start and/or end of the suite.

When using this method, you must make sure that this parent directory is the suite that you run. In other words, you must run your test like `robot XYZ` and *not* `robot XYZ/X1`.